# Samsung KNOX Cloud SDK - fetch MDM profiles

Tags: android, rest, mdm, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-knox

I am trying to implement Samsung KNOX cloud SDK into our MDM solution.

I have been following the [Getting Started guide](https://seap.samsung.com/tutorial/get-started-samsung-knox-cloud-sdk#Activate-a-Device).

To setup the stage for where i am at at the moment, i have gone through these steps by now:

- Got Acess to the **KNOX Cloud SDK**

  - Created the following keys **Cloud REST API KEY**, **KLM** and **ELM**
  - Implementet the steps from the Getting Started guide into our MDM service. This works fine when enrolling the device, I get all the responses from the Samsung Enterprise Gateway (SEG) server.
- Got acess to **SAMSUNG KNOX MOBLIE ENROLLMENT DASHBOARD**

  - Setup an MDM profile with x509 Certificate, pointing to ur MDM Url, with no Authtentication enabled
  - Add devices, and linked the to an MDM profile

After i create a MDM profile in the **SAMSUNG KNOX MOBLIE ENROLLMENT DASHBOARD**, and enrolling the devies, i try to fetch the profiles from our MDM service, via the SEG https://eu-segm-api.secb2b.com/v2/profiles/MyProfileID (this is the profile url in the json response i recieve on the first enrollment response from the SEG).

I am also passing along the X-Knox-Apikey in my request header, and the profileId.

The json response i get when trying to fetch the profiles, or send a push-notification is this:

```
{
  "status": "NOT_FOUND",
  "error": {
    "errorDescription": "Profile not found"
  }
}
```

How do i fetch my MDM profiles, i have the profileId, but when i try to fetch it i just get the above JSON response?